# How to handle the progress bar using Robotiium

Tags: android, robotium

I am automating an application using Robotium, where after inputing the credentials, progress bar appears on the screen. Here i'm facing an challenge, as progress bar is not an activity so i cant use the solo.waitForDailogToClose() method.

Please let me know how to detect and handle this progress bar. I'm using solo.sleep, but if progress bar takes more than specified time, then in tearDown  method it wil not close the application and hangs my next test execution.

Thanks,
Md Ashfaq

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue:

```
do {
    solo.sleep(1000);
} while(!solo.getCurrentViews(ProgressBar.class).isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
private boolean progressBarVisible() {
    if (mSolo.getCurrentViews(ProgressBar.class).isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    ArrayList<ProgressBar> barView = mSolo.getCurrentViews(ProgressBar.class);
    for (ProgressBar elt : barView) {
        if (elt.isIndeterminate()) {
            if (Config.DEBUG) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "still visible ");
                Log.d(TAG, "not indeterminate ");
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after you login.

```
while(!solo.waitForView(ProgressBar.class,1,1000))
{
}
```

This loop will continue until the progress bar becomes invisible. Also, you can define any criteria and use a `break` statement to exit from the loop.